# Does union all have an enforced ordering

Tags: mysql, innodb, union

I know that a union does a de-duplication so can jumble the results, but I can't find a definitive answer for union all

Example query

```
select id from
(
 select id from table where id = 1
 union all
 select id from table where id = 2
) as t
limit 1
```

If the table has 1, 2 in it, will 1 always be returned for the query or can 2 appear?

Engine is currently MyIASM but I'd also appreciate an answer for InnoDB.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee. `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` means that, whether it's a `UNION`, `UNION ALL` or any other subquery.

Comment: If the limit statement is removed, does the union all statement then have an enforced order? As in will the first query always return first in the set

Comment: What is the motivation for the question? Are you looking for a way to avoid executing the second query if the first returns a result?

Comment: Pretty much. Its a high latency situation. A union like this was one of the options we came up and we didn't know if there would be an enforced order or not, thus the question.

Comment: If both parts of UNION ALL read the same table and your underlying concern is how to speed up the query, you could try the approach as in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513129/mysql-count-id-that-appear-in-2-colums/17560469#17560469 "Mysql count id that appear in 2 colums") (of mine). That may not work equally well for UNIONing sets retrieved from different tables.